# Stream video from a secured endpoint using Angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, jwt, video-streaming

I have secured endpoint. I need to pass a jwt token in the head of a Http Get request from Angular to stream the video.

The endpoint in a dotnet core controller looks like this (simplified):

```
[Route("api/GetVideo/{videoId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideoAsync(int videoId)
{
    string videoFilePath = GiveMeTheVideoFilePath(videoId);  

    return this.PhysicalFile(videoFilePath, "application/octet-stream", enableRangeProcessing: true);
}
```

Angular code:
**video.component.html**

```
<video width="100%" height="320" crossorigin="anonymous" controls #videoElement>
        <source
            [src]="'http://mydomain/api/GetVideo/1' | authVideo | async"  type="application/octet-stream"
        />
</video>
```

**video.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'authVideo',
})
export class AuthVideoPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthTokenService) {}

    transform(url: string) {
        return new Observable<string>(observer => {
            const token = this.auth.getToken(); //this line gets the jwt token
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });

            const { next, error } = observer;

            return this.http.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(response => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(response);
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    observer.next(reader.result as string);
                };
            });
        });
    }
}
```

It does make a get request to the endpoint with the above code. And something is returned to the front-end. But the video is not playing. I found the above way from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115219/1978254). It works for images, but that doesn't work for video apparently. My thought is that I might need to read the streams byte by byte in the front-end. If so, how do I do that?

I have tried changing "application/octet-stream" to "video/mp4" on both ends. But no luck.

Note that when I removed security code from the back-end, and removed the authVideo pipe from the html it works perfectly. Please shed me some light. Thank you!

Comment: how did you slove this issue

Comment: I end up moving the video streaming endpoint behind a domain that is guard by a security service. So, whoever opens the video endpoints without login will be redirected to the login page. When the user is logged in, the video can be streamed via a normal HTML video tag. The downside is that whoever consuming the video endpoint has to repeat the code in the controller. If you have to create a standalone video streaming service, you can consider calling the video service from a secured backend. That way you don't need to expose the actual service endpoint to the client.

Comment: "you can consider calling the video service from a secured backend" can you tell me more about this. it will be really helpful. my application is like user can post the video and only login user has to see the video. videos are not supposed to be public.

Comment: you can try get only the endpoint first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this solution works for images because all of the data is loaded **once** as a data URL, you shouldn't be doing this for a video as it disables the streaming ability of the browser. Indeed by doing this you are loading the entire video **in memory** before transforming it into a data URL, which is really bad in terms of performance and user experience (requires the full video to be loaded before playing it, and causes heavy memory consumption).

The obvious solution to your problem is to use cookies for authentication:

- A cookie is set when the authentication succeeds
- It is automatically sent back in subsequent requests, including the video one

In the following I'm assuming you can't do that for some reason.

You could use [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/MediaSource). It allows you to control the actual request that is sent to retrieve the video (and add the `Authorization` header).
Note that even if this is widely supported by all of the browsers, this is experimental.

Your code should look like this:

```
assetURL = 'http://mydomain/api/GetVideo/1';

// Modify this with the actual mime type and codec
mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

@ViewChild("videoElement") video: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (
    "MediaSource" in window &&
    MediaSource.isTypeSupported(this.mimeCodec)
  ) {
    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    (this.video.nativeElement as HTMLVideoElement).src = URL.createObjectURL(
      mediaSource
    );
    mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", () =>
      this.sourceOpen(mediaSource)
    );
  } else {
    console.error("Unsupported MIME type or codec: ", this.mimeCodec);
  }
}

sourceOpen(mediaSource) {
  const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(this.mimeCodec);
  const token = this.auth.getToken(); //this line gets the jwt token
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });
  return this.http
    .get(this.assetURL, { headers, responseType: "blob" })
    .subscribe(blob => {
      sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", () => {
        mediaSource.endOfStream();
        this.video.nativeElement.play();
      });
      blob.arrayBuffer().then(x => sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(x));
    });
}
```

This [working demo](https://github.com/Guerric-P/Angular-MediaSource-demo) gives the following result:

[image: Request headers]

Comment: Thanks for Ans i tried it but for some reason its not able to stream let try again from scratch

Comment: I can't help without debug details, but I can tell it works I've tested it.

Comment: can you add the HTML part as well?

Comment: The HTML is just a `video` tag with a `#videoElement` template reference (no `src`), I can share the full project if you need it.

Comment: if possible, please. I'm stuck on this form so long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231644/discussion-between-avinash-reddy-and-guerric-p).

Comment: my issue is with web API replace "application/octet-stream" with "video/mp4" it started working. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. sad thing that the bounty is gone 

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. I can give now

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the URI of the webApi is the same as the main application, which is gaurded by an authentication service. The flow basically works like this:
[image: Video Streaming]

Before a request has reached the webApi endpoint, the authenticationService will determine whether the user is allowed to view this endpoint. e.g. whether the user is logged in, does the user have permission to view this endpoint, etc.

If a request has come to the webApi controller, the rest is pretty simple. It can just call the method in the videoService that returns the video stream.

In the frontend, all you need is this(of course you can make the videoId dynamic):

```
<video width="100%" height="320" controls #videoElement>
    <source
        [src]="'http://mydomain/api/GetVideo/1' | async"
    />
</video>
```

The back will look like this:

```
[Route("api")]
public class WebApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("GetVideo/{videoId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideoAsync(int videoId)
    {
        // Note: videoService can be on the same server, or a service
        // on a different server depends on how you implement it
        return this.videoService.GetVideoStream(videoId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one small thing for this request 'http://mydomain/api/GetVideo/1' where you have set the jwt token in angular can you just add that code.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the [Authorize] attribute from the WebApi controller. In my case, the domain is guarded by IdentityServer. Once the user is authenticated, the rest of the requests between the client and the server don't require a JWT token. If you need to secure the WeiApi controller, then you should try the answer by @Guerric P