# Angular 11 proper way to play videos in blob urls

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, blob

I am using html5 video tag to play videos in my Angular 11 application. The video source is from Asp Core Api which checks the user is authorize or not and returns video if user is authorize.
Angular Code :

```
<video controls preload="auto" *ngIf="videoLink" [source]="(videoLink | authVideo) | async" type="video/mp4">
```

AuthVideo pipe code :

```
@Pipe({
     name: 'authVideo'
})
export class AuthVideoPipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
      transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
          const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') })
          return this.http.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'blob' }).map(val => {
              return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val));
          })
    }
}
```

Asp Core :

```
[HttpGet("GetVideos")]
public IActionResult GetVideos(int VideoId)
{
    // Custom authorization checks from claims
    string filePath;
    filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                                    "wwwroot", "FolderName","Video.mp4");
    if(filePath != "")
    {
            return PhysicalFile(filePath, "video/mp4");
    }
    else
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

Reference : [Angular 4 image async with bearer headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563607/angular-4-image-async-with-bearer-headers)

My Question is when the video is return from server it creates the blob object, but it plays the video only after downloading the full video from server.
Note : When i do not use authVideo pipe, and directly use the api in video source then it shows partial content 206 and i am able to play it without full download file.

So how can i make it play using authorization as described and play without full downloading file.

Comment: Can anyone give any hint, as i did not find much about blob video playing in chunks.